# TFS Visual Studio Build task doesn't recognise macro DevEnvDir during post build event

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I have a Build definition with a Visual Studio Build task.

One of the projects has a Post Build Event command that use the macro $(DevEnvDir) but when TFS runs this task I get a compilation error because DevEnvDir is *Undefined*...

This doesn't happen when I build the solution through Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the DevEnvDir environment variable on your build server or add it into variables for build definition. The same posts:

1. [Team Build does not understand DevEnvDir](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/540c2273-2ad3-4a48-93ba-5fa6bda8c941/team-build-does-not-understand-devenvdir?forum=tfsbuild)
2. [Windows 7 Winforms ActiveX DEP and TFS](https://stevenovoselac.com/2011/01/13/windows-7-winforms-activex-dep-and-tfs/)

Guidance to add variable: [Set variables in pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline)

Comment: Post n.1 gave me the clue. I used $(VS110COMNTOOLS) instead of $(DevEnvDir).