# Wix Toolset Candle variable undefined in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, wix

Given:
Visual Studio 2019 Web API .Net Core 3.1
Wix Toolset 3.1.1
Windows 2016 Azure DevOps 2019

All I'm trying to do is use Wix Toolset to create an .msi file for a very simple WebAPI project.

If I run the SetupProject it works perfect:

```
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\candle.exe -d"DevEnvDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\\" -dSolutionDir=C:\apps\Solution1\ -dSolutionExt=.sln -dSolutionFileName=Solution1.sln -dSolutionName=Solution1 -dSolutionPath=C:\apps\Solution1\Solution1.sln -dConfiguration=Release -dOutDir=bin\Release\ -dPlatform=x86 -dProjectDir=C:\apps\Solution1\SetupProject1\ -dProjectExt=.wixproj -dProjectFileName=SetupProject1.wixproj -dProjectName=SetupProject1 -dProjectPath=C:\apps\Solution1\SetupProject1\SetupProject1.wixproj -dTargetDir=C:\apps\Solution1\SetupProject1\bin\Release\ -dTargetExt=.msi -dTargetFileName=SetupProject1.msi -dTargetName=SetupProject1 -dTargetPath=C:\apps\Solution1\SetupProject1\bin\Release\SetupProject1.msi -dWebApplication1.Configuration=Release -d"WebApplication1.FullConfiguration=Release|AnyCPU" -dWebApplication1.Platform=AnyCPU -dWebApplication1.ProjectDir=C:\apps\Solution1\WebApplication1\ -dWebApplication1.ProjectExt=.csproj -dWebApplication1.ProjectFileName=WebApplication1.csproj -dWebApplication1.ProjectName=WebApplication1 -dWebApplication1.ProjectPath=C:\apps\Solution1\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.csproj -dWebApplication1.TargetDir=C:\apps\Solution1\WebApplication1\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\ -dWebApplication1.TargetExt=.dll -dWebApplication1.TargetFileName=WebApplication1.dll -dWebApplication1.TargetName=WebApplication1 -dWebApplication1.TargetPath=C:\apps\Solution1\WebApplication1\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\WebApplication1.dll -out obj\Release\ -arch x86 Product.wxs
2>      C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\Light.exe -out C:\apps\Solution1\SetupProject1\bin\Release\SetupProject1.msi -pdbout C:\apps\Solution1\SetupProject1\bin\Release\SetupProject1.wixpdb -cultures:null -contentsfile obj\Release\SetupProject1.wixproj.BindContentsFileListnull.txt -outputsfile obj\Release\SetupProject1.wixproj.BindOutputsFileListnull.txt -builtoutputsfile obj\Release\SetupProject1.wixproj.BindBuiltOutputsFileListnull.txt -wixprojectfile C:\apps\Solution1\SetupProject1\SetupProject1.wixproj obj\Release\Product.wixobj
2>      SetupProject1 -> C:\apps\Solution1\SetupProject1\bin\Release\SetupProject1.msi
```

However, if I run it in Azure DevOps the DeEnvDir is undefined causing build to get hung (I'm guessing). I let it run for 12 minutes to be sure.

> d"DevEnvDir=*Undefined if not building from within Visual Studio*"

```
Compile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\candle.exe -d"DevEnvDir=*Undefined if not building from within Visual Studio*" -dSolutionDir=C:\agent2\_work\4\s\ -dSolutionExt=.sln -dSolutionFileName=Solution1.sln -dSolutionName=Solution1 -dSolutionPath=C:\agent2\_work\4\s\Solution1.sln -dConfiguration=Release -dOutDir=bin\Release\ -dPlatform=x86 -dProjectDir=C:\agent2\_work\4\s\SetupProject1\ -dProjectExt=.wixproj -dProjectFileName=SetupProject1.wixproj -dProjectName=SetupProject1 -dProjectPath=C:\agent2\_work\4\s\SetupProject1\SetupProject1.wixproj -dTargetDir=C:\agent2\_work\4\s\SetupProject1\bin\Release\ -dTargetExt=.msi -dTargetFileName=SetupProject1.msi -dTargetName=SetupProject1 -dTargetPath=C:\agent2\_work\4\s\SetupProject1\bin\Release\SetupProject1.msi -dWebApplication1.Configuration=Release -d"WebApplication1.FullConfiguration=Release|AnyCPU" -dWebApplication1.Platform=AnyCPU -dWebApplication1.ProjectDir=C:\agent2\_work\4\s\WebApplication1\ -dWebApplication1.ProjectExt=.csproj -dWebApplication1.Proje...
  Windows Installer XML Toolset Compiler version 3.11.2.4516
  Copyright (c) .NET Foundation and contributors. All rights reserved.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is no environment variable for `$(DevEnvDir)` when you build your solution in azure devops. You can try to define the `DevEnvDir` environment variable on your build server or add it into variables for build definition.

About defining variables, please view this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline). Here is a [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55721390/tfs-visual-studio-build-task-doesnt-recognise-macro-devenvdir-during-post-build) with similar issue you can refer to .